# Session_start() doesnt work on server(online)

Tags: php, session, localhost, host

I made login system which works fine on localhost, but when is on online server it doesnt work. There arent any errors, even if I type in wrong password, no errors. Nothing happens, it is on the same page always. [[http://sportcaffe.me/admin/]](http://sportcaffe.me/admin/%5d) <- You could try here, and see what it happens.. 
USERNAME: laky95
PASSWORD: lazar

I found some solution but it is not good... I can set session_start() on top of my code and It will work, but I have some session "prepare" and then start..
Here is my code:

```
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = FALSE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"],
    $cookieParams["domain"],
    $secure,
    $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

Comment: What was the solution when you said `I found some solution but it is not good..`? The one provided above?

Comment: I can set session_start() on top of my code and It will work
That is solution